# Error 1136: Column doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've tried to add this row at the DB, but i've the problem:
 `Error 1136: Column doesn't match value count at row 1`

the table is :

```
   Table: client
Columns:
CFCL varchar(16) PK 
CognomeCL varchar(30) 
NomeCL varchar(30) 
SessoCL varchar(1) 
ComuneNascitaCL varchar(20) 
DataNCL date 
IndirizzoCL varchar(30) 
TelefonoCL varchar(20) 
CittadinanzaCL varchar(30) 
PatenteCL varchar(10) 
DataSCL date
```

and this is the query that i made :

```
INSERT INTO cliente (CFCL, CognomeCL, NomeCL , SessoCL , ComuneNascitaCL, 
                     DataNCL, IndirizzoCL, TelefonoCL, CittadinanzaCL, PatenteCL, DataSCL) 
VALUES('MNA12OSQWDEWEWO8', 'Cognome', 'nome', 'F', 'Abbasanta', '1995-07-07', 'via pisa, 
        21', '0803597845', 'italiana', 'ba1234567q', '2020-07-07', 'mail@gmail.com');
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You have more values than columns. That last value (the email address) is errant.

Comment: 11 fields, 12 values, so... no duh...

Comment: You have 11 columns and you are inserting 12 values.

Comment: You have 11 column name specified but values you provide are 12

Comment: no, it's 12 values. `via pisa, 21` is a SINGLE string. note the quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355085/why-am-i-getting-error-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `'mail@gmail.com'`

```
INSERT INTO cliente (CFCL, CognomeCL, NomeCL , SessoCL , ComuneNascitaCL, 
DataNCL, IndirizzoCL, TelefonoCL, CittadinanzaCL, PatenteCL, DataSCL) 
VALUES
('MNA12OSQWDEWEWO8', 'Cognome', 'nome', 'F', 'Abbasanta', '1995-07-07',
 'via pisa, 21', '0803597845', 'italiana', 'ba1234567q', '2020-07-07');
```

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName where man 11 columns and 11 values ? where are 12 values ?

Comment: Tanks, i haven't add the email column at the table definition!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert more values...there are 11 columns where as you are trying to insert values to 12 columns.

1. remove the extra values in the insert query or
2. add the missed fields to the table.